Infinite loop space $QS^0$ and its zero component
I understand that $n$th homotopy group of infinite loop space $QS^0$ is $n$th stable homotopy group of sphere. But I read an article which says that the zero component of infinite loop space, denoted by $Q_0S^0$, represents stable homotopy theory.
My question is, what is exact definition of "zero component"? And why does it represents stable homotopy theory? Is there any reference about that?

"Zeroth component" means "component of the base-point". "Represents stable homotopy theory" is simply nonsense. But you said you already know that $\pi_n QS^0$ is the $n$th stable homotopy group of spheres, so... Please also tell us what article this is from.

@BenSteffan Dana Hunter's THE CURTIS-WELLINGTON SPECTRAL SEQUENCE THROUGH
COHOMOLOGY，in the beginning
